# Run Autosuggestion after 3rd letter, filter data for 36k entries

Tags: php, filter, autosuggest

I'm having a problem on a university website, which contains a list of 38.000 journals.

This list is displayed within a table of columns.

The column head #1 has a textbox to filter the rows below and 
The column head #2 has a dropdown filter to limit the search to specific databases.

It runs so far so good, but is a single HTML file of nearly 6MBytes.

I'm thinking of creating an SQL based table which will contain all the entries. That should be easy.

But how can I make textbox with autosuggestion which will start suggesting after 3 letters have been entered, and automatically the results are listed below?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: call the auto-suggest function if the input string is >=3

Comment: I guess I will use the code from http://papermashup.com/jquery-php-ajax-autosuggest/ but I'm not that good in PHP. Where to place the code you mentioned?

Comment: check my ans and let me know

Comment: Hi, I'm trying this script from http://www.codemashups.com/dynamic-search-filtering-using-jquery-and-php/ Any ideas where to implement the code you were talking about, and what would be the code look like? I'm not so good in scripting from scratch. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you may try to use DevBridge jQuery Autocomplete and specify minChars option. Check it out: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

call the auto-suggest function if the input string is >=3

```
if(inputString.length == 0) {
     $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
} else {
```

into

```
if(inputString.length == 0) {
         $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
} else if(inputString.length >= 3) {
```

Comment: Hi, I guess I've found something but I need to put in the "input string >=3" somewhere, but have no idea where. I hope you guys can help me out. The script is from codemashups.com/dynamic-search-filtering-using-jquery-and-php Again, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There are a million tutorials to do this on the net. Here is one: http://www.htmlblog.us/jquery-autocomplete

Plenty more here: http://www.google.com.au/search?q=jquery%20mysql%20autocomplete%20tutorial

Comment: Now I realized, that structure I'm working on, is not making it better. I guess I'll have to use ajax call function. So when typed into the textbox, it will be processed by another PHP file which in return will give the results. This will take a while for me...

Comment: Hi, I guess I've found something but I need to put in the "input string >=3" somewhere, but have no idea where. I hope you guys can help me out. The script is from codemashups.com/dynamic-search-filtering-using-jquery-and-php Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: From your codemashups tutorial, there is a line: `if(searchVal !== '') {`. Change it to: `if(searchVal.length >= 3) {`

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick. Last thing I have to solve is, it is searching for entries starting what is typed in. It should also be looking for entries which contain that string in a part of them. But anyway that helped me a lot.

Comment: There is a comment from Joseph on the website explaining how to do this. Change `name REGEXP '^$param'` to `name LIKE '%{$param}%'`

Comment: Thank you dwurf. Thanks to you I've finished the page.